# Does $z^0$ Have Multiple Solutions?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

While playing around with complex numbers, I stumbled upon a result that implies $z^0$ has infinitely many values (where $z$ is any complex number).  This struck  me as odd since I've never come across it before in my studies (and I think it violates the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra). I assume I made a mistake somewhere in my derivation but I cannot find it. Could someone please look through the steps below and help me understand where my error is?

I started by solving $z^i$:

Assume $z^i=w$
$$z^i=w$$
$$\ln(z^i)=\ln(w)$$
$$i\ln(z)=\ln(w)$$

Express $z$ in its polar form:
$$z=||z||e^{i(arg(z) + 2\pi n)}$$ where n is an integer that accounts for periodicity of the argument of z

Substitute in the polar expression for $z$ and simplify the logarithm:
$$i\ln(||z||e^{i(arg(z) + 2\pi n)})=i\ln(||z||))+i\ln(e^{i(arg(z) + 2\pi n)})=\ln(w)$$
$$i\ln(||z||))+i^2(arg(z) + 2\pi n)=\ln(w)$$
$$i\ln(||z||))-arg(z) - 2\pi n=\ln(w)$$

Invert the natural logarithm:
$$w = e^{i\ln(||z||))}e^{-arg(z) - 2\pi n}$$
$$z^i = ||z||^ie^{-arg(z) - 2\pi n}$$

Next I solved $z^{-i}$ using the same process with $m$ as the periodicity constant:

$$z^{-i}=w$$
$$\ln(z^{-i})=\ln(w)$$
$$-i\ln(z)=\ln(w)$$

Substitute in the polar expression for $z$ and simplify the logarithm:
$$-i\ln(||z||e^{i(arg(z) + 2\pi m)})=-i\ln(||z||))-i\ln(e^{i(arg(z) + 2\pi m)})=\ln(w)$$
$$-i\ln(||z||))-i^2(arg(z) + 2\pi m)=\ln(w)$$
$$-i\ln(||z||))+arg(z) + 2\pi m=\ln(w)$$

Invert the natural logarithm:
$$w = e^{-i\ln(||z||))}e^{arg(z) + 2\pi m}$$
$$z^{-i} = ||z||^{-i}e^{arg(z) + 2\pi m}$$

Now multiply the $z^i$ and $z^{-i}$ results together:

$$z^iz^{-i} = z^0$$
$$\left(||z||^ie^{-arg(z) - 2\pi n}\right)\left(||z||^{-i}e^{arg(z) + 2\pi m}\right) = z^0$$
$$\left(||z||^i*||z||^{-i}\right)\left(e^{-arg(z) - 2\pi n}*e^{arg(z) + 2\pi m}\right)=z^0$$
$$e^{- 2\pi n + 2\pi m}=z^0$$

Since $m$ and $n$ are just integers, you can just group them into one constant.
$$e^{2\pi n}=z^0$$
where $n$ is any integer.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: Probably m = n so m-n=0

Comment: I do not believe m has to equal n.  m=n is one of the possible solutions of course.

Comment: Here's a simpler version of your conundrum. $e^{2\pi i} = e^0 = 1$ therefore $\pi = 0$. If you do not want to arrive at contradictions, you should choose your phases coherently. Once you've fixed $n$ in $z^i = \lvert z\rvert^i e^{\theta + 2n\pi }$, you must also choose the same $n$ in $z^{-i} = \lvert z\rvert^{-i} e^{-\theta - 2n\pi }$. It's called choosing a branch of the logarithm.

Comment: There's some confusion about terminology here, as well. Since it's not an equation, $z^0$ doesn't have *solutions*. It does, however, have many different *representations* (but this shouldn't be surprising; $0 = -1 + 1 = -2 + 2 = \ldots$). Some expressions even have infinitely many *values*, for instance $i^i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose for instance: $z = i$

$i^i = \exp(i \ln i) = \exp \bigg[i^2 \bigg(\cfrac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}\bigg)\bigg] = e^{-\cfrac{\pi}{2}} e^{2\pi\mathbb{Z}} = A$

$i^{-i} = \exp(-i \ln i) = \exp \bigg[-i^2 \bigg(\cfrac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}\bigg)\bigg] = e^{+\cfrac{\pi}{2}} e^{2\pi\mathbb{Z}} = B$

Set A times set B:

$A \cdot B = e^0 \exp({2\pi \mathbb{Z} + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}}) = 1 \exp (2\pi \mathbb{Z}) = \{\exp 0, \exp ± 2\pi, \exp ± 4\pi, \cdots \}$

Therefore $i^i \cdot i^{-i} \neq \{1\}$

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now.  What I was doing in my question was similar to saying $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and $\sqrt{4} = -2$. Therefore $-2 = 2$.